# Piping file to http put request doesn't work when on vps

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days now and am not sure how to proceed. I have an ExpressJs server with an endpoint that accepts an image handled by multer and is then piped to an HTTP PUT request to bunny cdn storage. This whole setup correctly works when running on development, however, when I put the code on my VPS, it succeeds and I can see the `success: chunk` log but nothing is ever uploaded. On the VPS I'm using nginx with a reverse proxy pointing to the nodejs app.

A hint to what the problem could be was that before I was getting the following error: `Hostname/IP does not match certificate alt names`. To solve this I removed the `host` property from the `options` object and instead put the URL directly in the request which solved that. This problem was only present on the vps, not during local development.

Some other resources that could help would be the [bunnycdn documentation](https://docs.bunny.net/reference/put_-storagezonename-path-filename) for uploading a file.

This is the relevant code:

```
 let readStream = new Duplex();
 tmp.push(value[0].buffer);
 tmp.push(null);

  const options = {
    method: "PUT",
    path: `/${process.env.STORAGE_ZONE_NAME}/${value[0].originalname}`,
    headers: {
      AccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    },
    agentOptions: { checkServerIdentity: function () {} },
  };

  const req = https.request('https://storage.bunnycdn.com', options, (res) => {
    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
      console.log("success:", chunk);
    });
  });

  req.on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

  readStream.pipe(req);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You can start by putting in more error handling to see if you can catch the failure.  Put an error handler on `res` and on `readStream`.  And, obviously make sure you're able to see any of these errors that are logged in the console.

Comment: Also, this code doesn't show what's in `readStream`.  Could that be different?

Comment: Also note that the `pipeline()` function in the stream module does more complete error handling than `.pipe()` so you could try that with appropriate error handlers logging errors.

Comment: @jfriend00 the code in readStream is the file buffer. I omitted that code for clarity

Comment: Also I reworded my question, the upload doesn't fail. It actually succeeds and I get the `console.log("success:", chunk);` message logged

Comment: What role does multer play? Do you store the uploaded file on the server and read it from there into `readStream`? (Does your VPS allow storing files?)

Comment: No, I'm only using multer as middleware to handle the form data. The VPS allows storing files but I'm uploading the file directly from the request